# How to not request one specific google adsense if user on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, adsense

I have 2 adsense block on page now I use css media query check screen size hide one for width < n  one for width > n , now it works fine but the ad still load means been request, is it possible someway can detect if user on mobile device then not load specific block.

```
. AdMobile {
  display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 510px) {
  . AdDesktop {
    display: none;
  }
  . AdMobile {
    display: block;
  }
}

<div class="AdDesktop">
  <!-- adsense -->
</div>
<div class="AdMobile">
  <!-- adsense -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Check this website out, there you can find ready to use scripts to detect if the user is on mobile or desktop, that way you can tell if he is on mobile and hide the Adsense block.

Or you also can detect when the user is on mobile, and that way show a "responsive ad id" from the Google Adsense, which is also recommended for mobile.